# Is there support XC5VLX110 list in ISE Project setting?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise, virtex-series-fpga

I'm just trying to setup ISE envirmonent.
But There's not XC5VLX110 in Device list at the Project Settings in ISE as below picture.

[image]

What should I do for solving in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are using the WebPack edition? In which case [no, it is not supported](http://www.xilinx.com/publications/matrix/Software_matrix.pdf).

You need to use the ISE Design Suite version to support the Virtex 5 LX110. This requires you to purchase a software license.